# Mock method of system-under-test with Moq

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, moq

I have the following three methods in the CompanyApplication class (along with the supporting factories and services listed):

```
public ResultSet<CompanyDto> AddCompany(CompanyDto companyDto)
{
    var result = new CompanyDto();
    var company = new Company();
    Mapper.Map(companyDto, company);

    using (ITransaction t = _transactionFactory.Create())
    {
        company = _companyService.Add(company);
        t.Commit();
    }

    Mapper.Map(company, result);
    return new ResultSet<CompanyDto>(1, new[] { result });
}

public ResultSet<CompanyContactDto> AddCompanyContact(CompanyContactDto companyContactDto)
{
    var result = new CompanyContactDto();
    var company = new Company();
    var contact = new CompanyContact();
    Mapper.Map(companyContactDto, contact);

    using (ITransaction t = _transactionFactory.Create())
    {
        var contactCompanies = FindByIdJoin<Company, CompanyDto>(companyContactDto.CompanySK);
        Mapper.Map(contactCompanies.Data.First(), company);
        company.CompanyContacts.Add(contact);
        company = _companyService.Update(company);
        t.Commit();
    }

    Mapper.Map(contact, result);
    return new ResultSet<CompanyContactDto>(1, new[] { result });
}

public ResultSet<T_DtoType> FindByIdJoin<T_DbType, T_DtoType>(long id)
{
    IAbstractRepository<T_DbType> repository = EnsureRepository<T_DbType>();
    T_DbType entity = repository.FindByIdJoin(id);
    return (entity == null ? null : MapResultSetToDto<T_DbType, T_DtoType>(entity));
}
```

There are other objects in play here, which is why the `FindByIdJoin` has been made a separate method in the CompanyApplication class.

I have set up the testing class with some mocks and an instance of the CompanyApplication class:

```
private Mock<ICompanyRepository> _mockCompanyRepository;
private Mock<ICompanyDomain> _mockCompanyService;
private Mock<ITransactionFactory> _mockTransactionFactory;
private Mock<ITransaction> _mockTransaction;
private CompanyApplication _companyApplication;

[Setup]
public void SetUp()
{
    _mockCompanyRepository = new Mock<ICompanyRepository>(MockBehavior.Strict);
    _mockCompanyService = new Mock<ICompanyDomain>(MockBehavior.Strict);
    _mockTransactionFactory = new Mock<ITransactionFactory>(MockBehavior.Strict);
    _mockTransaction = new Mock<ITransaction>(MockBehavior.Strict);

    _companyApplication = new CompanyApplication(
        _mockCompanyRepository.Object,
        _mockCompanyService.Object,
        _mockTransactionFactory.Object);
}
```

I am successfully able to test the `FindByIdJoin` and `AddCompany` methods directly in Moq like this:

```
[Test]
public void CanFindCompanyByIdJoin()
{
    var data = new Company {ObjectId = 1, Name = "Company1"};
    _mockCompanyRepository.Setup(x => x.FindByIdJoin(It.Is<long>(arg => arg == data.ObjectId)))
        .Returns(data);

    var result = _companyApplication.FindByIdJoin<Company, CompanyDto>(data.ObjectId);

    Assert.AreEqual(data.ObjectId, result.Data.First().ObjectId);
}

[Test]
public void CanAddCompany()
{
    var data = new Company {ObjectId = 1, Name = "Company1"};
    _mockCompanyService.Setup(x => x.Add(It.Is<Company>(arg => arg.ObjectId == data.ObjectId)))
        .Returns(data);

    _mockTransactionFactory.Setup(x => x.Create()).Returns(_mockTransaction.Object);
    _mockTransaction.Setup(x => x.Commit());
    _mockTransaction.Setup(x => x.Dispose());

    var dto = new CompanyDto {ObjectId = 1, Name = "Company1"};
    var result = _companyApplication.AddCompany(dto);

    _mockCompanyService.Verify(t => t.Add(It.IsAny<Company>()));
}
```

Those two tests pass just fine. However, I'm having trouble coming up with a test for `AddCompanyContact`, because it calls `FindByIdJoin` as part of its flow, and that seems to be getting in the way.

Specifically, is there a way to mock `var contactCompanies = FindByIdJoin<Company, CompanyDto>(companyContactDto.CompanySK)` in a test for the `AddCompanyContact` method?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was over complicating the problem... since `AddCompanyContact` calls `FindByIdJoin`, all I needed to do was mock the same interface that is used in `FindByIdJoin`.

Lesson learned: mock interfaces, not classes.

Answer (score 0):

There is two alternatives that i see depending on the amount of work that you want to do.

1. Wrap that call into a object and instantiate it using a IOC container. This is the one that i feel would take the most effort if you are not using one already.
2. Turn that call into a Func and make a method without that parameter that does the call. This approach has the disadvantage that the top call will be untestable but will allow access to the rest of the method.

Example Below:

```
public ResultSet<CompanyContactDto> AddCompanyContact(CompanyContactDto companyContactDto)
{
         AddCompanyContact(CompanyContactDto, ()=>
                                              {
                                                 return FindByIdJoin<Company, CompanyDto> companyContactDto.CompanySK); 
                                              }
}

public ResultSet<CompanyContactDto> AddCompanyContact(CompanyContactDto companyContactDto, Func<WhateverTheMethodReturns> findIdReplacement)
{
    var result = new CompanyContactDto();
    var company = new Company();
    var contact = new CompanyContact();
    Mapper.Map(companyContactDto, contact);

    using (ITransaction t = _transactionFactory.Create())
    {
        var contactCompanies = findIdReplacement();
        Mapper.Map(contactCompanies.Data.First(), company);
        company.CompanyContacts.Add(contact);
        company = _companyService.Update(company);
        t.Commit();
    }

    Mapper.Map(contact, result);
    return new ResultSet<CompanyContactDto>(1, new[] { result });
}
```